# wildfly-swarm trying to add JPA fraction

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly-swarm

I am trying to add JPA into a simple wildfly-swarm Rest API. I ran around in circle trying to follow the JPA example of the github page with no luck
[https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples/tree/master/jpa
My app is kind of a "hello world" REST API as am new to wildfly-swarm:
Can I get a step by step instruction on how to set up persistence, in a kind of "hello world" project like mine?
here is the repo https://github.com/desiby/swarm-rest

After adding JPA and H2 as a dependency and turning the "person" object into a persistence entity here is the error I get (same error after adding the hibernate dependency:

> ```
>     2017-08-26 01:39:38,386 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("parallel-extension-add") failed - address: ([]): java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYCTL0079: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.jpa
>     at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:115)
>     at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:890)
>     at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
>     at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
>     at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1322)
>     at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:468)
>     at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:387)
>     at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:349)
>     at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:397)
>     at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:366)
>     at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```
>
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from modules/org/hibernate/main/module.xml

Comment: I don't see many similarities. You did not define a persistence.xml and you did not use an Entitymanager. There is no JPA in your example yet.

Comment: Also, as you're using fraction auto detection (because you don't have any explicit WF Swarm dependencies in pom.xml), JPA won't be added unless you have any code that uses JPA classes like Entity and EntityManager, etc

Comment: @aschoerk I updated my code with JPA, entitymanager and persisence.xml and I get errors. I am guessing i need to do quite a few config on the database?

Comment: @Ken what configuration should I do in persitence.xml? should I add the hibernate stuff? I seem to get the same erros when I do

Comment: @Desire, you shouldn't need the hibernate dependency in pom.xml, that should be available anyway from JPA fraction of WF Swarm